# Javascript onreadystatechange function call priority

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript code, the problem is that first executed the function `getBestMovies4BestPCRating();` and after the `amovies.forEach(function(item) {`

any idea?

```
document.getElementById('sendMovies').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var movieIDs = document.getElementById('MovieIDs').value;
    var data = {};
    var amovies = {};
    var movies = {};

    data["movieList"] = '[' + movieIDs + ']';

    params = JSON.stringify(data);

    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

    var url = "http://............."
    http.open("POST", url, true);

    //Send the proper header information along with the request
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

    http.onreadystatechange = function() { //Call a function when the state changes.
        if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
            movies = http.responseText;
            amovies = JSON.parse(movies);

            amovies.forEach(function(item) {
                if (item.rating > 4) {
                    getEntitiesRatings(item.ratingsPK.userId, 0);
                }
            });
            getBestMovies4BestPCRating();
            convertmovies2table(bestMovies);
        }
    }
    http.send(params);

});

function getEntitiesRatings(userid, kind) {

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = " http://.............entities.ratings/" + userid;

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            if (kind == 0) {
                computeUserColleration(myArr, userid);
            }
            if (kind == 1) {
                bestUserMovies(myArr, userid);
            }
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();

}
```

Comment: Your `getEntitiesRatings` function is asynchronous.  They are *ran* before `getBestMovies4BestPCRating` runs, but don't *finish* until after.

Comment: And I don't see where bestMovies is assigned?  But Hazmat is correct, you're going to spin through your array and start a bunch of ajax requests, then attempt to process the results as an array with no knowledge that all the requests haved completed and the array been fully assigned.

Answer (score 1):

The functions are executed in the order you write them. However, the first function is asynchronous, so the result will not be immediately available.

Consider using a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) instead.

Also, try providing a minimal example next time. No need for all this cluster in the code to express your troubles.

Comment: is possible an example?